# Include a variable in the middle of NSString

Tags: objective-c

I currently tried to use this:

```
NSString *hello = @"Hello";
NSString *whatever = [hello stringByAppendingString:@", world!"];
```

it's possible to use this but it will make a lot of work  because my goal is to do something like this:

```
NSString = "Hello" +variable+ "My name is" +variable + ",Good day"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSString's method `stringWithFormat`

example

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@ My Name is %@ ",var1,var2]
```

or

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@ My Name is %@ ",@"Stack Overflow",@"FreelancsAndroidLovesyou"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this alternatively, if both values are same then you can do this,

```
NSString *string = @"Hello YOUR_NAME, My name is YOUR_NAME, Good day";
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"YOUR_NAME" withString:@"Your_desired_Name"];
```

**UPDATE**

If both values are different then you can do this,

```
NSString *string = @"Hello %@, My name is %@, Good day";
NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:string, variable1, variable2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NSString method stringWithFormat.

Objective C

```
NSString *strConcat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@ My Name is %@ ",var1,var2];
```

Swift

```
let strConcat = "Hello "+ strOne + " My Name is " + strTwo
```

OR

```
let strConcateSecond = "Hello \(strOne) My Name is \(strTwo)"
```